# How do you update files from OSMDownloader?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

After adding the .osm file to your project using the OSMDownloader plugin can the labels or shapes be updated? In other words, when an edit is made in OpenStreetMap and the edit happens to be in your area of interest (i.e. the area you downloaded with the plugin), how do you get the changes to be reflected in your project without having to re-download?
[image]

Comment: You would have to re-download. The alternatives are to use an OSM basemap or to give a try to vector tiles